# asp.net postgresql connection CRUD

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, postgresql

I have a problem with data management in the postgre database. I`m connected, now i want to add any value, but that what i wrote dosent work.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Label1.Text = "Połączenie z bazą danych zakonczońe sukcesem";
                NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=dt_PackageWarehouse;User Id=postgres;Password=321qweQAZ");
                conn.Open();
                NpgsqlCommand comm = new NpgsqlCommand();
                comm.Connection = conn;
                comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                comm.CommandText = "select * from magazynpaczek";
                NpgsqlDataAdapter nda = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(comm);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                nda.Fill(dt);
                comm.Dispose();
                conn.Close();
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Label1.Text = "Połączenie z bazą danych zakonczońe niepowodzeniem";
            }
        }
       
    
        protected void btnDodaj_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=dt_PackageWarehouse;User Id=postgres;Password=321qweQAZ");
            string query = "Insert into public.magazynpaczek(id, nazwafirmynadawcy, imienadawcy, nazwiskonadawcy, nrtelefonunadawcy, miastonadawcy, ulicanadawcy, nazwafirmyodbiorcy," +
                " imieodbiorcy, nazwiskoodbiorcy, nrtelefonuodbiorcy, miastoodbiorcy, ulicaodbiorcy, nrprzesylki, datadoreczenia) VALUES(@NFN, @txtIN, @txtNN, @txtNTN, @txtMN," +
                "@txtUN, @txtNFO, @txtIO, @txtNO, @txtNTO, @txtMO, @txtUO, @txtNP, @txtDD)";
            NpgsqlCommand comm = new NpgsqlCommand(query, conn);
            conn.Open();
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to  create and add a parameter for each insert value:

```
var query = "Insert into public.magazynpaczek(id, nazwafirmynadawcy, imienadawcy, nazwiskonadawcy, nrtelefonunadawcy, miastonadawcy, ulicanadawcy, nazwafirmyodbiorcy," +
                " imieodbiorcy, nazwiskoodbiorcy, nrtelefonuodbiorcy, miastoodbiorcy, ulicaodbiorcy, nrprzesylki, datadoreczenia) VALUES(@NFN, @txtIN, @txtNN, @txtNTN, @txtMN," +
                "@txtUN, @txtNFO, @txtIO, @txtNO, @txtNTO, @txtMO, @txtUO, @txtNP, @txtDD)";

IDbCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = query;

var parameter = command.CreateParameter();
parameter.ParameterName = "NFN";
parameter.Value = nfn;
command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

parameter = command.CreateParameter();
parameter.ParameterName = "txtIN";
parameter.Value = txtIN.text;
command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

.... and so on

conn.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```